# How do i handle this printer friendly CSS?

Tags: css, printing

I have a html page. With header Body and Footer.

In Body I have two section Primary(left) and Rail(Right). The primary contains the Article and rail contains some modules. I want to to write css that just prints the article in primary.

I have done

```
#header{display:none;}
#footer{display:none;}
```

these two properties work properly in print.css

but when i do #rail{display:none} it does not hides and i still get the entire body. If i hide elements appearing inside the rail they also hide. But the rail doesnt.

Can anybody suggest me what might be going wrong.

Comment: Do you have a public page that reproduces the issue? Without an example I would guess that the rule is not being matched (e.g. the element uses a class instead of id) or that the rule is being overridden by another `display` rule. This could be an inline style, a later `#rail` rule or a rule with higher specifity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the inline style of your `#rail` section, it might have somthing that overrides your `display:none;`. If it's still displayed, try to add `!important` after your `display:none;`.

I'm just guessing out there, but the best way to find out what's going wrong, is to load your page with your `print.css` and to search through it with Firebug or so...

Comment: As I told, you, load your page with the print.css instead of the standard one, before using Firebug...

Answer (score 2):

I found this jquery to work well, you can choose which fields to display in your printer friendly version, you can also add any css to the head, including files or simply just a couple of classes.

```
function printPage(){
      var w = window.open();

      var headers =  $("#headers").html();
      var field= $("#field1").html();
      var field2= $("#field2").html();

      var html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
        html += '<html lang="en-us">';
        html += '<head><style></style></head>';
        html += "<body>";

        //check to see if they are null so "undefined" doesnt print on the page. <br>s optional, just to give space
        if(headers != null) html += headers + "<br/><br/>";
        if(field != null) html += field + "<br/><br/>";
        if(field2 != null) html += field2 + "<br/><br/>";

        html += "</body>";
        w.document.write(html);
        w.window.print();
        w.document.close();
    };
```